# Homeomorphism between $S^1×S^1$ and $S^2$

Tags: general-topology

Are the two sets $S^1×S^1$ and $S^2$ homeomorphic?

I am thinking that they are not but I am not getting any argument for that.

Comment: $S^1 \times S^1$ is a torus - think about one circle lying flat, and extrude the other circle orthogonally along it. I think it is clear a torus is not homeomorphic to a sphere (for example, they obviously have different fundamental groups, i.e. a loop around a torus can't always be contracted)

Comment: Are you familiar with [fundamental groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group) or [homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics))?  What tools are available to you here?

Comment: @EricTowers  No sir. We haven't studied that.

Comment: So what is the answer to my second question: "What tools are available to you here?"

Answer (score 5):

Consider the loop $\{1\}\times \Bbb S^1$ in the torus $\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1$. Suppose there is a homeomorpism $f:\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1\to\Bbb S^2$. Then $f(\{1\}\times \Bbb S^1)$ is loop in $\Bbb S^2$. Now, $\Bbb S^2\backslash f(\{1\}\times \Bbb S^1)$ is disconnected. But, $(\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1)\backslash (\{1\}\times \Bbb S^1)$ is connected.

To show, $(\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1)\backslash (\{1\}\times \Bbb S^1)$ is connected, consider two any points, $(e^{i\theta_k},e^{i\psi_k})\in (\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1)\backslash (\{1\}\times \Bbb S^1)$ for $k=1,2$. Here $0<\theta_1,\theta_2<2\pi$ and $0\leq \psi_1,\psi_2\leq 2\pi$. Now, we have a path from $ (e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\psi_1})$ to $(e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\psi_2})$ and a path from $(e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\psi_2})$ to $(e^{i\theta_2},e^{i\psi_2})$. So  juxtapsoing these paths we have a path from $(e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\psi_1})$ to $(e^{i\theta_2},e^{i\psi_2})$. Hence,  $(\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1)\backslash (\{1\}\times \Bbb S^1)$ is path connected.

Next we have to show, $X:=\Bbb S^2\backslash f(\{1\}\times \Bbb S^1)$ is disconnected. To show this, note that, under stereographic projection we have, $X\simeq \Bbb R^2\backslash L$, where $L$ is a line homeomorphic to $\{f(1, e^{i\psi}):0<\psi<2\pi\}$. But, $\Bbb R^2\backslash L$ is disconnected. So we are done. And this completes the proof.

$$\textbf{Note:--  }\frac{\Bbb S^1\times\Bbb S^1}{\big(\Bbb S^1\times\{1\}\big)\cup \big(\{1\}\times\Bbb S^1\big)}\text{ is homeomorphic to }\Bbb S^2.$$